# Why does the icon of a PC show a blue screen?

Tags: finder, icon

So in Finder, Mac finds a Windows PC in the Network. When I right click on it and click Get Info, I see an icon that shows a computer monitor with a blue screen. By blue screen I mean a crashed PC. Why is this? Why not a normal desktop image?

Comment: "0942v8653" is right. You can also notice that the PC looks like an old one from the 2000s.
More generally, Apple love to put some jokes/references in its icons and source codes.

Comment: As an icon, it needs to be recognizable both at small and large sizes. I think a simple image like this works better than "a normal desktop image," with its tiny icons, etc. Also, I would guess that, even for regular users, that blue screen is recognizable as something only a Windows PC will do.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Because it was Apple's way of making fun of Windows. No reason other than that.

[image]

Comment: Kind of childish, isn't it?

Comment: @MaxRied Not childish, just a light-hearted dig at a competitor that seems to have been in the OS since about 2007. Most people won't even notice it and I expect it'll raise a smile from those that do. It's probably a little out-dated now though.

Comment: Now all Apple has to do to make fun of Windows is show a Windows 8 desktop

Comment: In fact, the file is named "public.generic-pc_**lame**.icns"

Comment: This image also shows when sharing a folder with samba from a linux machine in Finder. Ironically, Finder's features when it comes to accessing shared resources on the network leave much to be desired.